# Going from transfer function to state space model

Tags: transfer-function, math, state-space

This is section from Linear Systems Control by Hendricks, and it is about going from a transfer function to a state space: -

[image]

In eq. 2.40 they have a transfer function \$\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} \$, where \$Y(s) \$ has order \$n \$ (because the highest exponent of \$s \$ is \$n \$) and \$U(s) \$ also has order \$n \$.

Then, the author makes some manipulation to the transfer function and arrives at eq. 2.41. Now, \$Y(s) \$ has order \$n-1 \$ and \$U(s) \$ still has order \$n \$. So seemingly, the order of the numerator polynomial has been reduced by 1 out of nowhere...

**My question is**, how does the author go from 2.40 to 2.41? How does the order of \$Y(s) \$ decrease by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Linear_Systems_Control/BHU-IP6_VSgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=linear%20systems%20control%20hendricks&pg=PA22&printsec=frontcover), We have to perform [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division). When we divide a polynomial of order \$n\$ with another of order \$n\$, the quotient is a constant and the remainder is a poly nominal of order \$n-1\$.

So,
$$
\color{green}{\text{quotient}} \times \color{blue}{\text{divisor}} + \color{red}{\text{remainder}}
=
\color{green}{b_n} \cdot \color{blue}{(s^n + a_{n-1}s^{n-1} + \dots)}
+
\color{red}{b_{n-1}s^{n-1} + b_{n-2}s^{n-2} + \dots}
= b_n s^n + b'_{n-1}s^{n-1} +  b'_{n-2}s^{n-2} + \dots
$$

Order of \$Y(s)\$ doesn't decrease due to the presence of the stand alone \$b_n\$ in equation `(2.41)`.

Also, \$Y(s)/U(s) = B'(s)/A(s)\$ need not mean that \$Y(s) = B'(s)\$.